# Use make to clean outdated outputs

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have a make file with an automatic rule like:

```
%.o: %.c
  gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

And a source file `a.c`:

```
int main() {}
```

Running `make` will produce `a.o`. Now if I rename `a.c` to `b.c`, and run make again, it produces `b.o`. Is there some way for me to remove `a.o` when I delete a.c, **without removing all other .o files**?

For instance, is there some way I can provide a pattern (`*.o`, which matches `a.o` and `b.o`) and remove from it all generated/skipped files (`b.o`) to get `a.o`?

Comment: You'll need to provide a [minimal, complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you want to accomplish, what do you mean by "extra outputs"? Why would you want to delete source files? Also why are you using `$*` instead of `$@` and `$<` your recipe?

Comment: Words are hard... What about "outdated"? Basically outputs that were previously generated, but will no longer be generated since their source file is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested!)

```
ALL_OBJS := $(wildcard *.o)
WANTED_OBJS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(wildcard *.c)))

.PHONY: clean-orphaned
clean-orphaned:
        @rm $(filter-out $(WANTED_OBJS),$(ALL_OBJS))
```

I would test it by running `make -n clean-orphaned` or changing `rm` to `echo` and carefully checking which objects would be removed.

Personally I wouldn't bother with this, just remove `*.o` and rebuild. It seems highly unlikely that you rename files so often that rebuilding everything is a serious problem.

Comment: +1 for "Personally I wouldn't bother with this", I'm not sure it should be a makefile's responsibility to clean up detritus, it could result in deleting stuff you wanted to keep. Also `rm` => `$(RM)`?

Comment: @user657267 I did think about using `$(RM)` but that would do `rm -f` and I intentionally left that off, because (1) the rule should only try to remove files that we know do exist, so no errors for missing files, and (2) as you say the whole idea seems risky and could delete things you want to keep, and `-f` could make that even more likely!

Comment: True, the only reason I brought it up is I often have to write makefiles that work on windows.